# Create different page type for posts of each category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress template. I have many categories, like, Adventure, Sports, News. Now, each category have posts in it, I know `singlep.php` is generating the all kind of posts. Suppose, if you click on News, it will show all the posts related to News. Every posts is identified as same page type "Post". But, I want to call a separate Post php file instead of single.php, when Adventure is clicked. Means, when I am browsing the posts of Adventure category, then it should come from `example.php` . Example.php is the file that I want to link with Adventure. I need help regarding that. It will be like,

```
if (Category == Adventure)
call the example.php
else
single.php
```

Where should I focus to do this. Is there anything related to `functions.php` ? Also, how wordpress calls the `Single.php` ? So that I can instruct it to call my `example.php` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to edit your single.php ?

```
in_category ( int|string|array $category, int|object $post = null )
```

Sample from wordpress site itself

```
if ( in_category('fruit') ) {
    include 'single-fruit.php';
} elseif ( in_category('vegetables') ) {
    include 'single-vegetables.php';
} else {
    // Continue with normal Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // ...
}
```

[in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category). This also could be a reference, Template Hierarcy: [single post](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-).

---

This can be an option to customize header for each category for single post by adding custom header file and edit single.php file

At the very top of **single.php** file

```
if(in_category('apple')){
    get_header('fruits');
}elseif(in_category('cabbage')){
    get_header('vegetables');
}else{
    get_header();
}
```

Then creates your own custom header with the exact name as example code above as `header-fruits.php` & `header-vegetables.php`

Comment: I don't want to edit the single.php. Instead want to create a similar file example.php. Because, I want to add some codes in the header for each posts of a particular category and posts of other categories will be same as it was calling from single.php previously.

Comment: I need a small help, this is present in which file:- if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Comment: @Codelife updated the answer, is that what are you looking for?

Comment: @Codelife that is the start point of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) which may appear on every page (that needs the loop, of course).